# C# HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, post, get

I would like to know how to make an Http Web Request on C# via POST, not via GET.

I have this example working via GET:

[ASPX File](http://www.cityclub.com.co/uploads/Prueba01.aspx)
[ASPX C# File](http://www.cityclub.com.co/uploads/Prueba01.aspx.cs)

Now I wold like to know how to do a simple Http Web Request sending data via POST.

Thanks very much!!

Comment: http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/http-post-in-c-/12267.html

Comment: have you tried setting the Method to `POST` instead of `GET`?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple:

```
request.Method = "POST";

// Write parameters...
byte[] data = new ASCIIEncoding( ).GetBytes( parameters );
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
using ( Stream outStream = request.GetRequestStream( ) )
    outStream.Write( data, 0, data.Length );
```

Comment: How to you send multiple parameters via POST? Thanks :)

Comment: I mean, can you be more detailed in the format of the parameters var?? Thanks!!

Comment: It's the same as you would with GET - just separate them by the & symbol. eg "&var1=test&var2=hello"